# Referencing assemblies only available on Windows Mobile/CE

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, compact-framework, windows-ce

I have created a C# project which works as intended when tested on desktop.

However, when I run the executable on a mobile device using .NET CF 3.5 I get the following error: File or assembly name 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=2.0.0.0, etc etc.' or one of its dependencies, was not found.

If I understand correctly, this means that one of the assemblies referenced in the project is "desktop only" and is not present on the mobile device. So how can I get access to the .NET CF 3.5 equivalent and reference it in my project in Visual Studio?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a "Smart Device Project" to run your application on a Windows CE device. That project type will let you reference CF assemblies only. There are a lot of features that are not supported by the CF version, so your code maybe won't compile.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, where did you get the option to create a Smart Device project? I am using visual studio 2012 and cannot see that anywhere...

Comment: There's no support for CF 3.5 in Visual Studio 2012 and 2010. You need to develop the project with Visual Studio 2008. Sad, but true.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, do you know if 2008 is even available anymore? Can't find a download that works anywhere.

Comment: The express editions of Visual Studio 2008 don't support Smart Device Projects, so you need at least VS Professional. You should still be able to download VS from MSDN (if you're a subscriber) or buy it online. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Wow, that's a pain. I can only download it from MSDN if I purchased it at some point though can't I?

Comment: You can download VS from MSDN only if you're a subscriber and your subscription includes development tools (which is quite expensive, I think).

Comment: Used [VS2008 Pro](http://www.ebay.com/itm/261284139575), but it should still install.